# How do you line of Corona SDK images universally for all (or most) builds?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to place icons to tap on the screen but cannot think of a way to do this universally for all build. Is there any documentation that can help me? Currently, I've placed it like the following :

```
    local mapButton = display.newImage ("images/mapButton.png");
    mapButton.x = _W / 1.125;
    mapButton.y = _H / 6.5;
    mapButton.alpha = .25

    local theNorthTap = display.newRect(_W/3,_H/3.75,500,375);
    theNorthTap.alpha = 0
    theNorthTap.isHitTestable = true
    theNorthTap:addEventListener("tap", theNorthTap);
    function theNorthTap:tap(e)
        storyboard.gotoScene("theNorth",{
             effect = "slideLeft",
            time = "250"
        })
    end
```

This seems to work beautifully for android builds, but shows half offscreen for Ipad or tablet builds.

Answer (score 1):

I position everything relative to display.contentWidth / display.contentHeight.
I presume that your _W / _H is equal to that though but just in case..

For example, positioning on the top left corner would be something like:

```
object.x=display.contentWidth*0.25
object.y=display.contentHeight*0.25
```

If you want a more precise position, adjust using the anchor, so top left corner would become in that case:

```
object.anchorX=0
object.anchorY=0
object.x=0 -- Or the border distance you want
object.y=0
```

Comment: You should use `display.screenOriginX` and `display.screenOriginY` for 0,0; on longer devices, 0 will be in the wrong place.

Comment: So you would position like that: display.screenOriginX + display.contentWidth * 0.25 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - display.contentWidth is not really the width if display.screenOriginX isn't 0. The real width would be `display.contentWidth - display.screenOriginX * 2`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: What I usually do is create a simple library that stores all the values, then depend on that instead of recalculating everything when I need it. You can check out one such library [here](https://github.com/GymbylCoding/Dusk-Engine/blob/master/Dusk/dusk_core/misc/screen.lua)